# GCC 4.5.0: host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc

When "make check" for GCC4.5.0, such error was occured:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/tool/gcc-4.5.0'
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [check-fixincludes] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/tool/gcc-4.5.0'
make: *** [do-check] Error 2
```

How to solve this problem? please....... & Thanks~~~~~

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem as you; the reason which fixincludes doesn't exist is because you never finished running "make"([+](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48445)).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the check failed. The makefile tried to enter a directory that doesn't exist. What this means depends on the project you are trying to build.